# Copy specific rows based on a condition in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy certain cells if the word "FLAG" is a cell in that same row. 
For example, I have data in excel like the following:

[image]

So if the word Flag is in any of the cells I want to copy the Description, Identifier and Final Maturity columns (Columns A-C) as well as the corresponding date column. So for the first row (AA) under Jan/Feb there is the word Flag. I would want to copy over columns A-E to another worksheet or table.

I would like to use a VBA but I am not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do what you expect, each time it finds the word FLAG, the first 3 cells will be copied as well as the value for the given month will be copied to a new row, and if a second flag is found that will be copied to the next available row:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("Sheet2")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop through rows
    For x = 15 To 23 'loop through columns
    If ws.Cells(i, x) = "FLAG" Then 'if FLAG found in column
        NextFreeRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'get the next empty row of your wsResult sheet
        ws.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Copy 'copy first three cells in given row
        wsResult.Range("A" & NextFreeRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'paste into your Result sheet
        ws.Cells(i, x - 11).Copy 'copy the value for which there was a flag
        wsResult.Cells(NextFreeRow, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'paste in the fourth cell in the sheet wsResult
    End If
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: So this code worked the first time. But  I changed my table a little and modified the code and now it isn't working.. I might post a new question so it is easier to understand. Any help would be greatly appreciated!